# launching realcalc from a button array

Tags: java, android, button, android-intent

i'm trying to launch realcalc from within my app from a button but everytime i try it doesnt do anything.

Code for the button

```
case 15: {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent("uk.co.quarticsoftware.REALCALC");
            double x = 0;// Set initial value (double).
            if (!texts[n].getText().toString().equals("")
                    || !texts[n].getText().toString().equals(null))
                x = Double.parseDouble(texts[n].getText().toString());
            intent2.putExtra("X", x);
            // Launch calculator.
            startActivityForResult(intent2, 0);

            break;
        }// open Calculatorcase 7:
```

Since it is an array of buttons i use a switch case as some buttons have different functions. The switch case is contained within a single onclick listener block. All the buttons work fine but i cant seem to launch an intent. If i try this from a button on the first page of my app it seems to work. I did code the exception too in the case there is no google play or realcalc on the device  but i did not see the app going through the exceptions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.android.calculator2",
               "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
startActivity(i);
```

Taken from here [link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/792eb424da2f946e)

and this one work with me :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
                CALCULATOR_PACKAGE,
                CALCULATOR_CLASS));

                Calculator.this.startActivity(intent);
```